# Combinatorics counting clarification

Tags: combinatorics

Hello everyone I am currently studying combinatroics and was a little confused and see if I could get some clarification.
The problem is, if I have 6 distinct objects and would like to find the number of ways I can choose exactly three objects(no more or no less like I cant choose 2 or 1, only 3)from the 6 distinct objects(once i choose an object I can not rechoose the object so im assuing no repetition is allowed) would the answer be

C(6,3)

Or

C(6,3) - (C(6,2) + C(6,1) )

I belive its
C(6,3) - C(6,2) - C(6,1)
since I would like to remove the options that arent possible but im not sure if this is the right way of thinking about the problem

Comment: Are you familiar with what the value of $\binom{6}{3}-\binom{6}{2}-\binom{6}{1}$ even is?  You believe there are negative one ways to choose three objects?

Comment: Ask yourself what is **the definition** of $C(6,3)$, and you will answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Let's give an example so you can get it better:

Your object space is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ we call this $m$. Now you want to choose $3$ object each time, but you don't want to repeat previous elections.

You would have:

$\{1,2,3\}$

$\{1,2,4\}$

And so on...

In combinatorics we define this relation of combinations with $m$ elements taking $n$ elements at each time as:

$\binom{m}{n}$ = $\frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!}$

Thus in our little example we would have:

$\binom{6}{3}$ = $\frac{6!}{3!(6-3)!} = 20$ different groups, but take into account that in these groups the order is not relevant.

In combination world $m=6$ and $n=3$:

$\{1,2,3\}$ is the same as $\{3,1,2\}$

So each combination can be permuted by $n!$, to form a variation, where the order really matters.

Regarding to $\binom{6}{3} - \binom{6}{2} - \binom{6}{1}$, I have to tell you that this is not correct. Since:

$\binom{6}{2}$ gives you elements like $\{2,3\} , \{1,4\} \dots$ so you are not choosing 3 elements at a time.

Hope that you have understood the basics.